# Prove that the group algebras $\mathbb{C}Q_8$ and $\mathbb{C}D_4$ are isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory

I need to prove that group algebras $\mathbb{C}Q_8$  and $\mathbb{C}D_4$ are isomorphic. How can I do this?

Comment: What are your definitions of $\Bbb {CQ}_8$ and $\Bbb {CD}_4$?

Comment: $Q_8$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group, $D_4$ dihedral group of order $8$. Non-isomorphic groups of order $8$, both have the degrees of irreducible representations $1$,$1$,$1$,$1$,$2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if the degrees of the (complex) irreducible representations of $G$ are 
$$d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_l$$ then

$$\mathbb{C} G \simeq \prod_{j=1}^l M_{d_j}(\mathbb{C})$$

Comment: $\mathbb{C}G$ is semisimple. This makes the Artin-Wedderburn theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem) explicit.